# Postfix: mail going to spam

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, spam

All emails I send from my new server go to spam in Gmail (and sometimes yahoo).

I've never before sent out mass email or spam.

What I've already done:

1. Configured reverse DNS
2. Enabled DKIM
3. Verified my IP is not on spam lists
4. Verified I'm not an open relay

Here are the headers from the received message:
http://pastie.org/pastes/8450781/text?key=onxgrau1xinyqv7ridxrea

Really, can't seem to figure out why the mail just doesn't come through.

I'd **really** appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that kind of problem with Google Mail in the past. I had everything set up properly, just like you did and still had my mail going to GMail's spam folder. The best what you could do (what I did) is to keep marking the messages from your server is `Not spam`. Ask few of your friends to do the same.

*In time*, the issue should be resolved!

I recommend reading more from Google's Support:

### [Why messages are marked as Spam?](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858)

> If you're confident that the message is not malicious, click the Not
> spam button to move the message out of Spam and into your Inbox.
>
> To prevent these types of messages from being classified as spam in
> the future, you can do one of the following:
>
> - [Adding their email addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8933) to your Contacts list. Gmail
>   will deliver messages from members of your Contacts list to your
>   inbox, unless we know with high confidence that they are spam.
> - Creating a [filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/answer.py?answer=6579) so the messages are never sent to Spam.